How can I call a WebAssembly function in C?
I have a C file runtime.c like this:
#include <stdio.h>

extern int _5();

int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
    printf("%i", _5());
    return 0; }

And I have a WAT file 5.wat like this:
(module
    (func (export "_5") (result i32)
        i32.const 5))

What is the simplest way to link them together and run the result in Wasmtime?
I tried this using WASI SDK (clang and wasm-ld) and WABT (wat2wasm) and got an error:
> wat2wasm 5.wat -o 5.wasm
> clang runtime.c -c -o runtime.wasm
> wasm-ld 5.wasm runtime.wasm
wasm-ld: error: 5.wasm: not a relocatable wasm file

What is a relocatable wasm file? What am I doing wrong here?

What is __main__() in your c program?  Do you mean _5()?

Yes. The example is merged from various different examples, and I forgot to change that.
